# Error on chooseCRANmirror() in R 3.2.2

Tags: r

I have R 3.2.2 installed on a Windows XP Professional SP2 computer. When I type `chooseCRANmirror()` I get the following error:

```
> chooseCRANmirror()
Error in download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: ''
```

Even with this error I can continue and install packages as long as I select a non-HTTPS mirror. Any help to resolve the error is greatly appreciated.

Comment: (unrelated to R, apologies) As an infosec professional I am compelled to beg you to switch to an operating system that actually gets security patches and isn't the opportunistic target for every automated botnet herder on the planet. There's some irony in wanting to use a secure download method on _the most insecure platform_ right now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use an HTTP server/mirror instead of HTTPS. 
Same problem detected in one of the 'less insecure platforms' (CentOS release 6.7 )

Comment: Would `chooseCRANmirror(useHTTPS = FALSE)` do that?